HTTP Url is not redirecting for controller to from HTTP to HTTPS in ASP.NET MVC
I have a controller MapController in which I have written code that check if url contains http://nvmbd1bkh150v02.rjil.ril.com/FiberInventorylease/, then it should redirect to HTTPS - so this url: https://nvmbd1bkh150v02.rjil.ril.com/FiberInventorylease/
I want any url which contains
http://nvmbd1bkh150v02.rjil.ril.com/FiberInventorylease/../..

should be redirected to
https://nvmbd1bkh150v02.rjil.ril.com/FiberInventorylease/../..

This code it only works for http://nvmbd1bkh150v02.rjil.ril.com/FiberInventorylease/ and not for http://nvmbd1bkh150v02.rjil.ril.com/FiberInventorylease/../..
public ActionResult MapPage()
{
    #region Get UMS Groups Details

    if (!Request.IsLocal && !Request.IsSecureConnection)
    {
        string redirectUrl = Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:");
        Response.Redirect(redirectUrl, false);
        HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
}

What can I do to make it redirect to HTTPS for any HTTP link which has http://nvmbd1bkh150v02.rjil.ril.com/FiberInventorylease/
Update
Here redirectUrl = https://nvmbd1bkh150v02.rjil.ril.com/FiberInventorylease/

Check out this article on how to do this globally: https://tech.trailmax.info/2014/02/implemnting-https-everywhere-in-asp-net-mvc-application/

@marc_s : I tried 1st and 2nd example but it is not working
